# Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema

Tags: nodejs, angular, webpack, angular-cli

He comenzado un proyecto con angular.
Para ello ejecuté el siguiente comando en consola:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli

ng new proyecto-angular

cd proyecto-angular

ng serve
```

Pero me lanza el siguiente error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid configuration object. Webpack
>   has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match
>   the API schema.

Anteriormente había hecho el mismo paso con otro proyecto y este funciona correctamente, no sé por qué este no se ejecuta bien, alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué pasa esto?

Comment: el proyecto que quieres crear no esta dentro de otro angular cli?

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude solucionarlo cambiando el nombre de la carpeta en la que tenía el proyecto, quizás no funcionaba porque tenía el caracter "!" en el nombre, suelo ponerlo a algunas carpetas para que me aparezcan primero que las demás de izquierda a derecha en mi disco local.